# Opening new terminal in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, console, terminal

I am writing a shell script in Linux. I want to run some sh files in terminal and they all needs terminal themselves.
How can I open a new terminal to run another scrips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
xterm -e script arguments... &
```

Comment: Tnx. But now I have a problem. How can I open the terminal together? Next command waits for the new opened terminal to be closed

Comment: Add `&` at the end of the line.