# Ubuntu Shell Script opening two table and run two command using one shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I use two separate shell scripts to run my two server, one is Django and another is `npm`.

Django Command is: `python3 backend/manage.py runserver` and npm command is: `npm start`

I write shell script to run my Django server:

This is my `startserver.sh` file to run Django server

```
#!/bin/bash
python3 backend/manage.py runserver $1
```

and this is my `startnode.sh` file to run npm server

```
#!/bin/bash
npm start $1
```

both are working fine.

I want, when I run `./startserver.sh` in terminal, it should run this `python3 backend/manage.py runserver` command in the current tab of the terminal, in the same time, the script should open another tab in the terminal and run this command: `npm start`

I mean, in one shell script, I want to run two script in same windows two tab of the terminal.

I will just run `./startserver` and it should run above two command in two different tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution 1:

**tmux**

```sh
tmux new-session -d  1.sh \; split-window -h 2.sh \; attach
```

### Solution 2:

**gnome terminal**

Read : [Opening multiple terminal tabs and running command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/500357/opening-multiple-terminal-tabs-and-running-command)

```sh
for i in 1 2; do
    options+=($tab -e "bash -c '${cmds[i]} ; bash'" )
done

gnome-terminal "${options[@]}"
```

## Update

Read [Terminal Multiplexers](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_adv_termmux.php)

Answer (score 2):

I think this command will be help you.

```
xterm -e [your_args]
```

maybe `your_args` will be `startnode.sh`

In detail, you can script your startserver.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
python3 backend/manage.py runserver $1

xterm -e “./startnode.sh”
```

like this.

[Reference]
[Opening new terminal in shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19585409/opening-new-terminal-in-shell-script)
[Start xterm with different shell and execute commands](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/373377/start-xterm-with-different-shell-and-execute-commands)

Comment: How? Can you please write me full script?

Comment: @dudd Please refer to modified answer. I’m sorry I’m not in shell environment now so I couldn’t test this. I hope this works fine.

Comment: remove amp on the end of command. It makes your second terminal run on background.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have both scripts saved under your home directory called `a.sh` and `b.sh`. Then make another script combined.sh with the following

```
sh ~/a.sh &
sh ~/b.sh
```

Basically, you're just calling both scripts, but you background the first one to allow continuing execution to the next script.

Comment: Did you read the description? They should open new tab, those two command should run in two tab